How do I set a DNS search domain for an nm-devices
Where do I put the desired DNS search domain for an nm-devices netplan configuration (NetworkManager backend)?  I've tried "ipv4.dns-search" in the passthrough: section, but that doesn't seem to get applied, using either dnsmasq or systemd-resolved as the dns backend for NetworkManager (in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf).  resolvectl (when using systemd-resolved) is able to add the domain to that link and it takes effect.
